# Comparing corpuses with different vocabulary?

Tags: machine-learning, paired-comparisons, model-evaluation

How can we compare two corpuses with different vocabulary?

Basically, we have a bunch of distributions for different vocabularies that we want to compare. But all the vocabularies are different lengths (often two or three times one another).

One popular way of comparing corpus (of the same size) is comparing entropies. (1) If we just calculate the entropies, they are not comparable. 
(2) even when we normalize the entropies (divide by entropy of a uniform distribution of same size), the entropy of smaller vocabularies are pretty consistently lower.

Any ideas what is a good way of comparison in our scenario?